# how to display the element after parsing json in angular template?

Tags: angular

Here is the code

```
{{payment.metadata | json}}
```

This is what i am gettting

```
"{\"phoneNumber\":\"4163000477\",\"animalName\":\"Mustang\"}"
```

How to display the phone number? I have tried accessing it by this `{{(payment.metadata | json).phoneNumber}}`

Comment: No idea what that text from your previous question was, but it's now removed.

Comment: If your JSON is already parsed, you can simply use `payment.metadata.phoneNumber`. The `JSON` pipe is simply used to display JSON, but it looks like you want to display the actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this json use `JSON.parse(json)`. This method covert string to object. After that you could access to the field.

```
 let example = JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON);
```

HTML part:

```
{{ example.phoneNumber }}
```